# Area under the graph of a convex function

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, convex-analysis

Consider the following problem:

> Suppose that $f$ is a twice differentiable real function such that
> $f''(x)>0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Find all numbers $c\in[a,b]$ at which
> the area between the graph $y=f(x)$, the tangent to the graph at
> $(c,f(c))$, and the lines $x=a$, $x=b$, attains its minimum value.

The solution starts with the observation that the condition on $f''$ implies convexity of $f$, i.e. the graph of $f$ is always above any tangent to it, and therefore
$$A(c)=\int\limits_a^b (f(x)-f(c)-f'(c)\cdot(x-c))dx,$$
where $A(c)$ is the area the problem refers.

I'm really confused with this formula for the area and can't comprehend it even after drawing the picture. Can anybody explain it? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Convexity on differentiable functions is equivalent to $f(y) \geq f(x) + f'(x)(y-x)$ (the tangent line is below the function). Then, you don't need to worry about the sign of the diference between $f$ and the tangent since $f$ is always above the lines $x\mapsto f(c) + f'(c)(x-c)$ for every $c\in [a,b]$. Therefore, the distance between $f$ and the tangent line at $(c,f(c))$ is $f(x)-f(c)-f'(c)(x-c)$.

Comment: @LucasResende, thanks, it answered my question. If you want to post something along these lines as an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convexity on differentiable functions is equivalent to $f(y)\geq f(x)+f′(x)(y−x)$ (the tangent line is below the function).

Then, the point is that you don't need to worry about the sign of the diference between $f$ and the tangent lines, since $f$ is always above the lines $x\mapsto f(c)+f′(c)(x−c)$ for every $c\in[a,b]$. Therefore, the distance between $f$ and the tangent line at $(c,f(c))$ is $f(x)−f(c)−f′(c)(x−c)$.

So,
$$ A(c) = \int_a^b f(x)−f(c)−f′(c)(x−c) dx = \int_a^b f(x) dx - (b-a)f(c) + f'(c)\frac{ (a-b)(a+b-2c) }{2}.$$