# How to show that $A$ is increasing?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, optimization, area

> Suppose that $f$ is a twice differentiable real function such that
> $f''(x)>0$ for all $x\in[a,b]$. Find all numbers $c\in[a,b]$ at which
> the area between the graph $y=f(x)$, the tangent to the graph at
> $(c,f(c))$, and the lines $x=a$, $x=b$, attains its minimum value.

I understand that the area mentioned above is

$$A(c)=\int\limits_a^b (f(x)-f(c)-f'(c)\cdot(x-c))dx,$$

and using this formula I can get that $c= \frac{a+b}{2}$ is a critical point of $A$, but I'm falling to see why this has to be where $A$ attains, specifically, a minimum. If anyone could enlighten me, that would be wonderful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Area under the graph of a convex function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3782526/area-under-the-graph-of-a-convex-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have
$$
A'(c)=-f''(c)\int\limits_a^b(x-c)\,dx.
$$
Clearly, $A'(c)<0$ if $c<(a+b)/2$ and $A'(c)>0$ if $c>(a+b)/2$. Therefore $A$ is decreasing before the midpoint and increasing after, attaining a minimum at $c=(a+b)/2$.

Answer (score 0):

We want to find the minimum of the function $A(c)$, which will be located at a point where $A'(c)=0$ so:
$$A'(c)=-f''(c)\int_a^b(x-c)dx$$
now since we know that $f''>0$ this cannot equal zero so the integral must:
$$\int_a^b(x-c)dx=\left[\frac {x^2}{2}-cx\right]_a^b=\frac{b^2-a^2-2c(b-a)}{2}=0$$
now we need to solve for c, so:
$$2c(b-a)=b^2-a^2$$
$$2c=b+a$$
$$c=\frac{a+b}{2}$$
and there is your answer

Comment: But how do we know that $A(\frac{a+b}{2})$ is a minimum, not a maximum?

Comment: find a formula for $A''$ and see the sign of it for this value of $c$

Comment: But that would mean I need to know $f$ is 3 times differentiable, which I don't.

Comment: so instead analyse $A'$ around this point